# Navlink is nor routing toward component and collapse is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, reactstrap

So i Have added a navbar in my basic react project, when the screen is sm there appears a collapse i want to click on the collapse to show the navbar but its not working when I click on the button everthing goes away

And also i tried to route the navbar to one of my component but it doesn't work

*[*App.js**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/litbd.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MainComponent from './components/MainComponent';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
function App() {
  return (
<BrowserRouter>

<MainComponent />

</BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Navigation.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavItem , NavbarToggler,Collapse } from 'reactstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
class Navigation extends Component {


    constructor(props){

        super(props);
        this.state={

            isNavopen:true
        }
    }

    navToggle = () => {

        this.setState({

            isNavopen : !this.state.isNavopen
        })
    }


    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar dark color="danger" expand="sm">
                    <div className="container">
                        <NavbarToggler onClick={this.navToggle}/>
                        <NavbarBrand href="/">Game of The year 2021</NavbarBrand>
                        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isNavopen} navbar>
                        <Nav className="me-auto" navbar>
                            <NavItem>
                                <Link to="/" className="nav-link acitve">Home</Link>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <Link to="/menu" className="nav-link ">Menu</Link>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <Link to="/about" className="nav-link ">About</Link>
                            </NavItem>
                            <NavItem>
                                <Link to="/contact" className="nav-link ">Contact</Link>
                            </NavItem>
                        </Nav>
                        </Collapse>
                    </div>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Body.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Menu from './Menu';
import Home from './Home';
import Contact from './Contact';
import About from './About';
import { Route,Routes,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Body = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            {/* <Menu /> */}
            <Routes>

                <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/menu" exact component={Menu}/>
                <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact}/>
                <Route path="/about" exact component={About}/>
                </Routes>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Body;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell you are mixing up the `react-router-dom` v5 route syntax when you are using v6.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
  <Route path="/menu" exact component={Menu}/>
  <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact}/>
  <Route path="/about" exact component={About}/>
</Routes>
```

In version 6 of `react-router-dom` the `Route` components no longer take `component` or `render` props, and instead render the routed components on the `element` prop ***as JSX***. The updated routing code could work as following:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
  <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
  <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

In v6 routes are always exactly matched, and the `element` prop takes a JSX literal, or `ReactElement`.

[image: Edit navlink-is-nor-routing-toward-component-and-collapse-is-not-working]

If for some reason you *are actually* still on v5 and just mixed in the v6 `Routes` component, switch back to using the `Switch` component. `Switch` was replaced by `Routes` in v6.

```
import { ..., Switch, ... } from 'react-router-dom';

<Switch>
  <Route path="/menu" component={Menu}/>
  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
  <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
  <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Routing link is working now but if i click on the collapsable button whole thing turns blank in white page. What is I am missinh ?

Comment: @RizviAhmedZillhaz I was about to ask what the `NavbarToggler` did but then I realized it was a mobile view size thing. I don't think I can reproduce the issue you describe after toggling the `isNavopen` state via the button. Feel free to fork my codesandbox and replace the stubbed components.

Comment: I don't know what is actually causing this issue